# Is this statement about measurable function true?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f$ is a measurable function on $[0,1]$, then there exists a measurable set $D\subset [0,1]$ such that $mD>0.9$, and a continuous function $g:[0,1]\to R$ such that $f=g$ on $D$.

My question is that how can we approximate a measurable function by continuous function and how good could it be? Is there any theorem for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant result is called Lusin's theorem. This should really be thought of in two different parts: $f$ restricted to the set $D$ is a continuous function in the subspace topology of $D$; and this restriction can be extended back to $[0,1]$ to get a continuous function.

So for instance, $1_{[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}}$ is continuous when restricted to $[0,1] \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$, and can be continuously extended to the constant function $0$. For another example, a function with a single jump at $1/2$ is continuous on the complement of $(1/2-\delta,1/2+\delta)$ for any $\delta>0$. One can continuously extend from there, for instance by linear interpolation.

This last example demonstrates how one might prove the second part: given a small bad set which is chosen arbitrarily, make it slightly bigger in order to make it *open*, and then extend linearly across each of the open intervals which were deleted.

Comment: I just saw Lusin's theorem. And as it states, given any $\epsilon>0$, we can find a compact set of [0,1] whose measure is larger than $1-\epsilon$, and $f$ is continuous on it. But if we do not need the compactness, can we say it is continuous except for a set of measure zero?(It sounds wrong, but I'm confused with these two definition....)

Comment: Even dropping the compactness you still must excise a set of positive measure.